# While using projection query in GAE datastore, null is returned instead of a String value (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am working with Projection Queries for GAE Datastore.

I have a use case where I need to fetch only the distinct values from under a property in the datastore.

It seems that projection query is working, but it returns the result as null instead of the actual value.

Following is the piece of code:

```
Query q = new Query(user.getEmail() + "_" + job);
    q.addProjection(new PropertyProjection(prop, String.class));
    q.setDistinct(true);

    PreparedQuery pq = datast.prepare(q);
    String elements[] = new String[1000];
    int i=0;
    String s="";
    for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
          elements [i] = (String) result.getProperty("" + prop);
          //i++;
          s = s + elements[i] + ",";
          resp.getWriter().println(elements[i]);
          i++;
        }
```

The 'elements' array has tthe distinct count but contains 'null' instead of actual string values.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Only indexed properties can be projected.
>
> Projection is not supported for properties that are not indexed,
>   whether explicitly or implicitly. (Long text strings (Text) and long
>   byte strings (Blob) are not indexed).

From what you describe it appears that this property is not indexed.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Volgin, I had indexed all the properties, yet it is not returning the values, actually I am getting the exact result count i.e. suppose there are 3 distinct values under a kind, the loop runs exactly 3 times, but the value fetched in the array contains null. Is there an issue with fetching the projection queries?

Comment: Did you re-save all entities after indexing the properties?

Comment: No, I didn't, can you please guide through the process

Comment: All properties are indexed only when an entity is saved. So if you changed your code after an entity was saved, it needs to re-saved for the indexing to work.